# Understanding .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

I stumbled upon this `.htaccess` file and am trying to figure out what it does.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !upload\.php$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,H=default-handler]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Line above says , you activate mod_rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
```

Line above is a condition to be applied with URI , URI is a part of path after host not including query string http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html , for example http://example.com/whatever/index.php , /whatever/index.php is the URI part in this case , then there is **!/$** with means **!** not end **$** with **/** so this condition will match any URI that not ends with **/**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !upload\.php$
```

Two line above also are conditions to don't match URIs that end with either index.php or upload.php

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L,H=default-handler]
```

Above line illustrates the rule that should applied according to those conditions and it includes Pattern , substitution and flags , you can read more here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html and herein means any request passes conditions above will be handled by default handler , So the Pattern is **^** which is regular expression https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html means matches the beginning of the string and substitution is **-** which means do nothing then the flags [L,H=default-handler] , **L** means stop processing the rule set , **H** means forces the resulting request to be handled with the specified handler and it is default handler in your case .

see this about flags https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html and this to understand handler https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/handler.html

Comment: Thank you very much! This really helped!